# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

**Intent** :- I am trying to display data using JSP connecting with database Oracle 12c. I have included OJDBC jar in WEB-INF folder as well as in JAR folder.

[Project hierrarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGWKP.png)

**JSP Code Written is** :-

```
<% Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); %>

<head>
    <title> Tablename database table</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>The table name database </h1>
```

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>CLAIMID</th>
        <th> First Name</th>
        <th> Last Name </th>
    </tr>
    <% while(resultSet.next()){ %>
    <tr>
        <td> <%=resultSet.getInt(1)%></td>
        <td> <%=resultSet.getString("SUBNAMEFIRST")%></td>
        <td> <%=resultSet.getString("SUBNAMELAST")%></td>
    </tr>
   <% } %>
</table>
</body>
```

Resources Used :-

Tomcat Server 7.0
Idea 10.5.2

**Error coming** :-

```
Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP: 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\nbalodi\.IntelliJIdea10\system\tomcat\Unnamed_JavaEEHelloWorld\work\Catalina\localhost\_\org\apache\jsp\DBDataUI_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. javax.servlet resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Show jsp file DBDataUI_jsp

Comment: Look into your catalina.out logfile and you should get more informations. It is not good to use DB Access directly in a jsp. Learn about the MVC and DAO pattern

Comment: Error says that you import package: `import javax.servlet;` This is not possible. You can import class or interface from this package.

Comment: *Only a type can be imported. javax.servlet resolves to a package*

Comment: BTW, JSP should be used as a view, not for doing DB lookups, put this code into a servlet or other webservice

Comment: Thanks Everyone, I just removed <%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %> and it worked. I will try with MVC and DAO patterns as suggested.